# Error installing mexopencv

Tags: macos, matlab, opencv

I am trying to interface Matlab and OpenCV by installing `mexopencv` on my Mac, and I had the following error message:

```
>> mexopencv.make
make MATLABDIR="/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app" MEXEXT=mexmaci64  
make: pkg-config: Command not found
make: pkg-config: Command not found
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/mex -c -cxx -largeArrayDims -Iinclude  src/MxArray.cpp -outdir lib
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
In file included from /Users/Alberto/Documents/Data_analysis/mexopencv-master/src/MxArray.cpp:6:
include/MxArray.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
         ^
1 error generated.

make: *** [lib/libMxArray.a] Error 255
```

I installed OpenCV using Brew. Do you have any suggestion on how to make the installation work? Thanks!

Comment: Installing `mexopencv` on a Mac was the biggest pain I've ever experienced.  However, I managed to get it to work by following these instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773916/compiling-mexopencv-in-os-x-10-9-with-xcode-5-and-matlab-r2013b.  Not sure if these will work for you, but give it a try!

Comment: The `mexopencv.make` function [calls](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/%2Bmexopencv/make.m#L162) the system's `make` to execute the `Makefile`. This in turn [uses](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/master/Makefile#L16) `pkg-config` to locate the OpenCV headers and shared libraries. So you must have `pkg-config` available on the PATH. So if you open a terminal and type `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` you should get the compilation and linking flags for the installed OpenCV library. If not, install `pkg-config` and add it to PATH then set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` accordingly

Comment: This thread might help: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I simply replaced the lines which called pig-config like this:

`CV_CFLAGS  := -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/include`

where the output is what i got from running pkg-config --cflags opencv from terminal. Do this too for the CV_LDFLAGS using --libs and remove the check above that which does a `pkg-config --exists opencv etc` call.

The next error I got was some `-lippicv` related thing, which I fixed by adding this to the Makefile.

`override LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/`